# "No such file or directory" error when trying to install pcre

Tags: compiling

am using ubuntu 12.04 and am trying to install pcre however I encountered an error message when I tried to use the command:

sudo make after the ./configure command.

I have this error message

```
/bin/sed: can't read Files/PCRE/pcre-8.30/libpcre.la: No such file or directory
libtool: link: `Files/PCRE/pcre-8.30/libpcre.la' is not a valid libtool archive
make[1]: *** [libpcreposix.la] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/dimaz/Downloads/Snort Files/PCRE/pcre-8.30'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I am completely new at this, but I had the same error when trying to unpack the tarball for TeX Live on Ubuntu 12.04.

What I did was open the file in the Archive Manager. Then open the file manager in the terminal with this command

```
xdg-open file
```

It found the file then.